# Extending components in Scala with more specific return types

Tags: scala

The following does not compile:

```
trait Text {
  trait Token
  def tokens: Seq[Token]
}

trait PosText extends Text {
  trait Token extends super.Token {
    def tok: String
  }
}

def foo(p:PosText) = p.tokens.map(_.tok)
```

with this error

> value tok is not a member of p.Token

it will compile if I override the tokens method.

Is there a way of defining the types to get return type for Tokens to be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can define an abstract type member `Token` instead of a trait and then concretely provide the type in the implementation. Here's a working example:

```
trait Text {
  type Token
  def tokens: Seq[Token]
}

trait PosText extends Text {
  type Token <: PosToken
  trait PosToken {
    def tok: String
  }
}

def foo(p: PosText) = p.tokens.map(_.tok)
```

Comment: That was my first solution, but it can't be extended any further. Trying to add yet another layer extending PosText will not be possible

Comment: It's possible provided that types are compatible, i.e. you can override `Token` once it's defined by assigning it to a subtype of `PosToken`. If that's not the case, there's probably some flaw in the design.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella It isn't possible if you write `type Token = PosToken`; when overriding a type member you can only add constraints, so once you fix a precise type you can't override it with a subtype. Instead you need `type Token <: PosToken`.

Answer (score 0):

Generics can be more convenient for this case because they can have variance:

```
trait Text[+Token] {
  def tokens: Seq[Token]
}

trait PosText[+Token <: PosTextToken] extends Text[Token]

trait PosTextToken {
  def tok: String
}

def foo(p:PosText) = p.tokens.map(_.tok)
```